# Ant Design forms how to achieve this

Tags: reactjs, antd

How to achieve this design in **antd forms** for react? I have tried with suffix, but I'm unable to achieve the exact layout.

[image]

Comment: I believe you can use `addonAfter` if `suffix` does does not achieve the exact layout. Usage of `addonAfter`:

`<Input addonBefore="http://" addonAfter=".com" defaultValue="mysite" />`

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `addonAfter` and you can specify this using a react-component:

```
<Form.Item name={['user', 'age']} label="Age" rules={[{ type: 'number', min: 0, max: 99 }]}>
    <InputNumber addonAfter={<span>mm</span>}/>
</Form.Item>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/nest-antd-4-24-3-forked-3o0f4y